# How do I reposition this fade to get it in the right place

Tags: html, css

I have a simple 2 panel layout, where the left panel scrolls, the right one doesn't. I want to add a fade to the right hand side of the scrolling div, but so far I've either got it so the fade is in the right place, [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/tomharto/vzpp72Lz/1/), or it's static, but outside of the target area, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/tomharto/vzpp72Lz/).

What do I need to do differently to get the fade to be in the correct place?

```
html,
body,
.row,
.row > div {
  height: 100%;
}
.content:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5%;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,b7b7b7+100&0+0,0.65+100 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(183, 183, 183, 0.65) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(183, 183, 183, 0.65) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(183, 183, 183, 0.65) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6b7b7b7', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.bar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9 bar clearfix">
    Menu
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3 content">
    Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />Content
    <br />
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

1. Use `fixed` positioning
2. Set `right` to `25.5%` to match the ratio of one column to the other through Bootstrap's classes
3. Add `@media` query to handle smaller screen size to set `right` back to `0`

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m9h9hfkj/1/)

Comment: On my actual page at the moment, I've had to bump it up to 26.5%, but works like a treat, thanks :).